# how to opt for discounted rate when converting currencies in paypal?

Tags: india, paypal, withdrawal

I read http://trak.in/tags/business/2016/08/25/paypal-slashes-forex-rates-paypal-me-p2p-payments/ and specifically this part -

> While accepting payments, the user needs to opt for the discounted
>   rate for converting their currencies. - trak.in

Does anybody know what the author is talking about ?